# User have to buy coins to call someone in my Android App. Which one is better, Google Pay or Google In-App Billing for my scenario?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment, google-pay

I'm developing an Android application in which user have to buy coins to use features of app. I want to know which is the best way to achieve my goal. I have read about Google Pay and Google In-App billing, but i am unable to understand which payment type should be implemented in my case. I have calling feature in my app, user have to buy coins to use this feature, a certain amount of coins will be deducted per minute when user calls someone, so user have to buy coins first.

I want to know if Google Pay is better or Google In-App billing is better for my application. Or if there is any other way to do this, i would really appreciate your opinion. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to use google pay, then the users are required to install a separate application for which user may/may not have enough space in their device.
Also, Google pay has many payment issues in the recent times. Money is being deducted from your account but is taking time to be added to benefiter's account.
So, Google's In-App Billing best suites for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. If i implement Google's In-App Billing, where would the transactions be shown, i mean is there any dashboard from where i can see transaction details? Can you provide any good Tutorial or sample application.